# Curl breaking the sscript

Tags: php, curl, prestashop

I have such a weird problem with CURL in PHP. The thing is, i'm communicating with local database through API which returns JSON. I'm using CURL to do it and the exact way I do it, is that first all the categories are fetched then, within foreach, CURL is called again for each of the categories to fetch the products in it. We were moving the website to new server and the thing stopped working all of a sudden and I can't tell why.

So, everything works fine and the products are being fetched correctly until the 4th category (which is larger I'm assuming). After the fourth category the script stops running and it doesn't output anything to the screen.

I've tried numerous things, changing memory_limit in php.ini prolonging time limit and whatnot. The result is always the same and the output is this

[image]

After 04, Hello should be outputted as should all the other categories (atleast 20 of them)

Here's a piece of my CURL code within foreach function.

```
foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' ';
    $fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/errorlog.txt', 'w');
    $fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/response'.$key.'.txt', 'w');
    $url_get_products = $url.$key;
    $ch = curl_init($url_get_products);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_NONE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    $redirectURL = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL );
    curl_close($ch);
    echo 'Hello<br>';
```

I've even managed to get the output to a file and it seems it's working properly when I output it to the file but the script still stops running.

Then, since I know which categories are the reason behind this problem I've even separated it outside the foreach loop which redirected me to 404 page on my server.

Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: Hard to tell without more information. You're using the same file pointer for both files, so only the response file is being used. Check for errors in the server logs, and see if there's anything in the files.

Comment: If you place anything after the foreach loop, does that output? Or does the script simply "die" somewhere within the loop?

Comment: @aynber i've checked error logs and there's nothing in it

Everything outputs normally before the loop and within the loop until it gets to the curl of the 04 category and then it simply stops working after that and nothing outputs to the screen

Comment: @JesusChrist I asked about after. Place any output after the foreach loop and check if the script reaches that code. If it does it is something wrong with the way you cURL. If the code after the loop is never reached it is crashing somewhere before that.

Comment: @OptimusCrime I've accidently pressed yes. I'm not that experienced with CURL and in my opionion for whatever reasons it's not returning the proper data but it's crashing (or maybe redirecting the page to something else. Therefore that 404 page). I can't even output curl_getinfo. It just stops somewhere in the middle

Comment: Does it result in a 500 error? What does the error log say?

Comment: No it doesn't result in anything it just ends. It's like there's an exit() called after that curl is called. It looks exactly like this http://prntscr.com/e9hyqs

Comment: What if you use a different file handle for the stderr and CURLOPT_FILE?  You shouldn't share the same file handle between both, that may cause problems aside from mixing debug info with your curl responses.

Comment: @drew010 I overlooked that but still, initially I wanted my script to output to screen and the general idea is to get the all products to an array where i'll validate them. That was working before but for some reason it just stops.

Data outputted to the file is the same as what's outputted when I use the url in my browser. Something after that just breaks down since the script doesn't echo the next line or gives me an opportunity to list the curl errors.

Comment: What if you put an echo before and after `curl_exec`? is it getting that far?  Also, try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the top of the script just in case something is being masked